# How come this doesnt draw rounded corners?

Tags: javascript, canvas, quadratic-curve

I am trying to draw a rectangle with rounded corners, so far only the top corners are rounded, But the bottom two corners are not somehow? Full code: https://github.com/GunZi200/Memory-Colour/blob/master/SourceCode.js

**Can you guys spot the error?**

```
        ctx.fillStyle = rectangle.color;
        ctx.moveTo((rectangle.x + 40 - 30) * Xf, (rectangle.y + 30 - 30) * Yf);
        ctx.lineTo((rectangle.x + 40 + 40) * Xf, (rectangle.y + 30 - 30) * Yf);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo((rectangle.x + 60 + 30) * Xf, (rectangle.y + 30 - 30) * Yf, (rectangle.x + 60 + 30) * Xf, (rectangle.y + 50 - 40) * Yf);
        ctx.lineTo((rectangle.x + 60 + 30) * Xf, (rectangle.y + 60 + 30) * Yf);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo((rectangle.x + 60 + 30) * Xf, (rectangle.y + 80 + 30) * Yf, (rectangle.x + 50 + 40) * Xf, (rectangle.y + 80 + 30) * Yf);
        ctx.lineTo((rectangle.x + 40 - 40) * Xf, (rectangle.y + 80 + 30) * Yf);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo((rectangle.x + 30 - 30) * Xf, (rectangle.y + 80 + 30) * Yf, (rectangle.x + 30 - 30) * Xf, (rectangle.y + 70 + 40) * Yf);
        ctx.lineTo((rectangle.x + 30 - 30) * Xf, (rectangle.y + 50 - 40) * Yf);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo((rectangle.x + 30 - 30) * Xf, (rectangle.y + 30 - 30) * Yf, (rectangle.x + 50 - 40) * Xf, (rectangle.y + 30 - 30) * Yf);
```

[image: Example of code above]

Comment: That looks like a lot of work.  Maybe doing it with CSS would satisfy your requirements: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_borders.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't check your code, but here is a generic function to draw a rounded rectangle:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var x=50;
var y=50;
var w=50;
var h=35;
var direction=1;
ctx.strokeStyle='gray';
ctx.fillStyle='orchid';
ctx.lineWidth=5;

animate();

function animate(){
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  roundRect(x,y,w,h,10);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();

  w+=direction;
  h+=direction;
  if(w<50 || w>100){
    direction*=-1;
    w+=direction;
    h+=direction;        
  }

}

function roundRect(x,y,width,height,radius) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x + radius, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + width - radius, y);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius);
  ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius, y + height);
  ctx.lineTo(x + radius, y + height);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y + radius);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
  ctx.closePath();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: In my full code I start with a small rectangle, then I increase some lengths and decrease others by 1 until they reach 30 or 40, depends. The picture & code above is just when the rectangle has reached its last frame. Im trying to use this to make an animation.

Comment: I changed my code to show a rounded rectangle animating in size.

Comment: The animation I am using, the small rect starts in the middle, and its size increases in all directions until it fits into the "rounded" border.

Comment: Fair enough...Draw a squared-corner rectangle until the size reaches full-size minus radius. Then start drawing a rounded rectangle with a radius that starts small and increases as the rectangle increases. Good luck with your project!